# View hashes in varnishlog 4.0.5

Tags: varnish

I cannot seem to be able to view the hashes in my varnishlog.  I have already gone into varnishadm and altered by vsl_mask setting so it is now set to `-VCL_trace,-WorkThread`

But when I run varnishlog, and hit the page with curl, whilst I see a load of data (including the vcl_call and vcl_return for the hash) I do not see any lines detailing what is being stored in the hash.

Is there an important step I have missed to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if you can print out the hash in human readable format anyway.
id prefer to use `std.log()`  inside `vcl_hash` - which you ll see in `varnishlog`